# Get and Set Data CheckboxList on Table in Asp Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, parameter-passing, checkboxlist

I wrote a class and set public IActionResult Index():

```
    public class SuperBowl
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public bool GiftPackage { get; set; }
    }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            double[] pricearraying = { 630, 500.25, 385.75 };
            string[] namearraying = { "Red", "Green", "Blue" };
            var heyinitial = new List<SuperBowl>();
            for (int i = 0; i < pricearraying.Length; i++)
            {
                heyinitial.Add(new SuperBowl { Name = namearraying[i], Price = pricearraying[i], GiftPackage = false });
            }
            return View(heyinitial);
        }

[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(List<SuperBowl> ceko)
{
            double[] exposalary = { 63.00, 42.00, 21.00 };
            var choosing = new List<double>();
            foreach (var item in ceko.Select(x=>x.GiftPackage))
            {
                if (item == true)
                {
                    choosing.Add(exposalary[ceko.FindIndex(r=>r.GiftPackage==item)]);
                }
            }
}
return View("MyCheckOut",choosing);
}
```

And Here is my Index.cshtml:

```
@model List<SuperBowl>
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
        <div class="table-responsive-sm table-hover">
            <table align="center" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table-light text-center">
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>My Price</th>
                        <th>Hey Gift</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var st in Model)
                    {
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <td asp-for="@st.Name">@st.Name</td>
                            <td asp-for="@st.Price">@st.Price</td>
                            <td asp-for="@st.GiftPackage">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => st.GiftPackage)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="CheckOut" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is MyCheckOut.cshtml:

```
@model List<double>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-responsive-sm table-hover">
        <table align="center" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-light text-center">
                    <th>Our Discount Numbers</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var discounting in Model)
                {
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <td>@discounting</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My expect is that when I tick only Red which indice is 0, then via the same indice 0, let's get array exposalary[0] which is 63.00
or when I tick Red and Blue which these indices are 0 and 2, then via the same indices 0 and 2, let's get array exposalary[0] and exposalary[2] which are 63 and 21.

If I deploy all these codes, in Index.cshtml my table seems good and every data is Ok on the other hand when I choose any checkbox submitting and send my choice in MyCheckOut, there is no element.

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your codes , for example it's `GiftPackage` not `GiftPacage` in your page .

The key to complex object binding is ensuring that a sequential index in square brackets is added to the form field's name attribute in your case . So modify your `Index.cshtml` as :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  <tr class="text-center">
      <td asp-for="@Model[i].Name">@Model[i].Name</td>
      <td asp-for="@Model[i].Price">@Model[i].Price</td>
      <td asp-for="@Model[i].GiftPackage">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].GiftPackage)</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Another problem is The `findIndex()` method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. So you will get multi same value if multi selection is made from checkbox . Update your action code to :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(List<SuperBowl> ceko)
{
    double[] exposalary = { 63.00, 42.00, 21.00 };
    var choosing = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ceko.Count; i++)
    {
        if (ceko[i].GiftPackage ==true)
        {
            choosing.Add(exposalary[i]);
        }
    }


    return View("MyCheckOut", choosing);
}
```

Comment: Writing class and item's name, there can be a problem in here, you're right but your solution is exactly true. Thank you very much.
I see that my problem is using List.Select insistly rather than List[i]. Here is my main fault. Thank You, Sir.